# swfupload session problem destroy session

Tags: php, session, swfupload

I have a problem with swfupload. I am passing session_id() like this

Note : It is working fine on my local machine, am using MAMP. but its not working at server

```
  /upload-file.php?s='<?php echo session_id()';
  /upload-file.php?s=189477fcfa1ec7f630e70a09e1e84cae
```

but its not maintaining session and destroying my current session (logging me out) here is code in file upload.

```
<?php

 if(isset($_GET['s'])) {

session_id($_GET['s']);
session_start();

    require_once 'admin/class/user.php';

    $u = new User();

    //Check for user logged in

    if($u->islogged() == FALSE) {

      header("location: index.php");

   exit();

    code continue ..... 
 }
```

because am not logged in server redirect me to the index.php

this is swfupload debugger window output

```
 SWF DEBUG: ----- END SWF DEBUG OUTPUT ----
 SWF DEBUG: 
 SWF DEBUG: Event: fileDialogStart : Browsing files. Multi Select. Allowed file types: *.jpg
 SWF DEBUG: Select Handler: Received the files selected from the dialog. Processing the file list...
 SWF DEBUG: Event: fileQueued : File ID: SWFUpload_0_0
 SWF DEBUG: Event: fileDialogComplete : Finished processing selected files. Files selected: 1. Files Queued: 1
 SWF DEBUG: StartUpload: First file in queue
 SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadStart : File ID: SWFUpload_0_0
 SWF DEBUG: ReturnUploadStart(): File accepted by startUpload event and readied for upload.  Starting upload to /upload-file.php?s='189477fcfa1ec7f630e70a09e1e84cae' for File ID:  SWFUpload_0_0
 SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress (OPEN): File ID: SWFUpload_0_0
 SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress: File ID: SWFUpload_0_0. Bytes: 317793. Total: 317793
 SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadError: HTTP ERROR : File ID: SWFUpload_0_0. HTTP Status: 302.
 SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadComplete : Upload cycle complete.
 SWF DEBUG: StartUpload: First file in queue
 SWF DEBUG: StartUpload(): No files found in the queue.
```

Comment: `Starting upload to /upload-file.php?s='189477fcfa1ec7f630e70a09e1e84cae'` - should those single quotes be there?

Comment: I tried it without and with quotes, same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your swfupload js:

```
  var swf;
  window.onload = function () {
   swf = new SWFUpload({
    // Backend Settings
    post_params: {"PHPSESSID": "<?php echo session_id(); ?>"}
...
```

Comment: my script is working fine on my local machine, am using MAMP and its working fine. but its not working at server

Comment: Just an basic ruff idea. Try to set token for an upload form (and set it in a hidden form field) and store it with your session id in db before sending. In the next step get hidden form field and check it against database. Get the session id for that token and restore it :) Should work.